# Update badge count on app icon without push notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on android application on which I need to show count on app icon when ever I receive value from api. I am able to update badge value on app icon through notification, but I am unable to update badge count on app icon without notification.

so my question is, do we always need a notification to update count on app icon?

I checked what's app and found that the count on app icon increased through notification but they have clearly mention on their site that **Badge count is a notification functionality provided by your launcher and is not a function of WhatsApp. If you continue to experience issues, please contact your phone's manufacturer.**

so again my question is how the count is getting decreased after reading the message, suppose the count is 59 and after reading one message count goes to 58?

Comment: We have researched this before and unfortunately there is no way to update the count without notification. However, when you update it through notification, you can set any value you want. Some custom launchers allow you to update badges without notification but probably 99% percent of your users will be using official launchers so it's a waste of time to develop for a specific custom launcher that noone is using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can do it.
By default, you can create a onGoing Notification builder and notify with priority is LOW, and at the same time, you display by ShortcutBadger.
Make sure the notification is silent mode.